# how to control html stylesheet hierarchy?

Tags: html, css

I have a test.html which uses multiple stylesheets. When opened the file from the local drive (not going through webserver), the styles were applied differently when compared to loading the files from webserver. Can this happen?. How to control this from happening?

attached is the comparision image from chrome browser  developer tools styles listing.

[image]

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a caching issue; the browser using a cached version when visiting the live server.

Comment: An easy way to check if it is a caching issue is go into the chrome developer tools (F12) and click the settings gear in the bottom right.  Check the `disable cache`.  Anytime you load a page while developer tools are open for that tab, it will ignore caches and fetch it all.

Comment: I agree with @Alex it may be caching issue. CSS are server independent because they are handeled by browser. However, css files may be cached by some mods.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. But seems not a cache issue. Because I have cleared the cache and tried disabling cache as suggested by @DMoses. still the same.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments, this looks like a browser caching issue.

> A web cache stores copies of documents passing through it; subsequent requests may be satisfied from the cache if certain conditions are met.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache

Try hitting F5 to refresh the page or disable cache. Usually, it is done through the Developer Tools in a browser (F12).